# determine if number belongs in set with multiple normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I am attempting to work with data with a few of normal distributions mixed in with each other. What I am thinking is splitting up the data in to the separate  distributions and then calculating the standard deviation of each.

An example would be something like:
    [1,2,3, 7,8,9, 14,15,16]
What I want the algorithm to do is generate something like: [avg: 2 std: .81, avg: 8 std: .81, avg: 15 std: .81]

The problem that I am running into is that I can not find an effective way to split the numbers up into different groups.  I am also wondering if this is even the best way to go about determining if a number belongs in a set of numbers when there is more than one normal distribution.